# Extracting Business Days and Business Day of Current Month in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm looking to do two things - I'm trying to a.) only extract business days within a month and b.) what business day it is of the month its in.

So I know the business day portion can be done by using the DAYOFWEEK function and getting rid of all days that equal 1 or 7, but I'm a bit stumped on how to solve the business day of month portion. For example, today would be the 21st business day of this month, but the 21st business day of another month might not be the 29th, so it wouldn't make sense to compare that sort of way. It could be a weekend. For the purposes of making this simple, we don't need to worry about holidays that fall on a typical business day (i.e Memorial Day).

So my goal is basically to have an output that gives you -

Column 1: ID (lets just say this is some three character randomly generated alphanumeric ID)

Column 2: start_date

Column 3: Day of week

Column 4: business day within start_date month

Anyone have any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Extracting Business Days between Start and End Date

In below example Start Date is '2016-06-01' and End Date is '2016-06-30'

```
SELECT 
  DATE(DATE_ADD(TIMESTAMP('2016-06-01'), pos - 1, "DAY")) AS business_day
FROM (
     SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER() AS pos, *
     FROM (FLATTEN((
     SELECT SPLIT(RPAD('', 1 + DATEDIFF(TIMESTAMP('2016-06-30'), TIMESTAMP('2016-06-01')), '.'),'') AS h
     FROM (SELECT NULL)),h
)))
HAVING DAYOFWEEK(business_day) NOT IN (1,7)
```

> Finding Nth Business Day between Start and End Date

In below example Start Date is '2016-06-01' and End Date is '2016-06-30' and N = 21

```
SELECT 
  business_day
FROM (
  SELECT
    business_day,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY business_day) AS number
  FROM (
    SELECT 
      DATE(DATE_ADD(TIMESTAMP('2016-06-01'), pos - 1, "DAY")) AS business_day
    FROM (
         SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER() AS pos, *
         FROM (FLATTEN((
         SELECT SPLIT(RPAD('', 1 + DATEDIFF(TIMESTAMP('2016-06-30'), TIMESTAMP('2016-06-01')), '.'),'') AS h
         FROM (SELECT NULL)),h
    )))
    HAVING DAYOFWEEK(business_day) NOT IN (1,7)
  )
)
WHERE number = 21
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but just a question of clarification... where would my table name go?

Comment: my answer gives you an idea with solid example, but if you want actual implementation - you need to provide more info on your case  - what is the input and what is expected output. so far this was not a part of your question.

Comment: So basically there is a field called start_date that gives you a date formatted in YYYY-MM-DD... I'm not really sure what you would need?

Comment: what is your input data (show example for few rows) and what is expected output- add these in your question

Comment: Gotcha. So my goal is basically to have an output that gives you -

Column 1: ID
Column 2: start_date
Column 3: Day of week
Column 4: business day within start_date month

Comment: Thanks! Edited my initial question

Comment: i add another answer with best attemp to address your additional comments. hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Try below

```
SELECT
  start_date, 
  business_day, 
  DAYOFWEEK(business_day) AS day_of_week,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY start_date ORDER BY business_day) AS business_day_number
FROM (
  SELECT 
    start_date, DATE(DATE_ADD(TIMESTAMP(start_date), pos - 1, "DAY")) AS business_day
  FROM (
    SELECT start_date, ROW_NUMBER() OVER() AS pos
    FROM (FLATTEN((
      SELECT start_date, SPLIT(RPAD('', 1 + DATEDIFF(TIMESTAMP(end_date), TIMESTAMP(start_date)), '.'),'') AS h
      FROM 
        (SELECT '2016-01-01' AS start_date, '2016-01-31' AS end_date),
        (SELECT '2016-03-01' AS start_date, '2016-03-31' AS end_date),
        (SELECT '2016-06-01' AS start_date, '2016-06-30' AS end_date)
    ), h
  )))
  HAVING DAYOFWEEK(business_day) NOT IN (1,7)
```

)

in my mind - you changed original question - so I felt it is appropriate to provide separate answer instead of adding to my original one

> where would the table name go?

assuming YourTable looks like below:

```
start_date  end_date     
2016-01-01  2016-01-31   
2016-03-01  2016-03-31   
2016-06-01  2016-06-30
```

the query will look like

```
SELECT
  start_date, 
  business_day, 
  DAYOFWEEK(business_day) AS day_of_week,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY start_date ORDER BY business_day) AS business_day_number
FROM (
  SELECT 
    start_date, DATE(DATE_ADD(TIMESTAMP(start_date), pos - 1, "DAY")) AS business_day
  FROM (
    SELECT start_date, ROW_NUMBER() OVER() AS pos
    FROM (FLATTEN((
      SELECT start_date, SPLIT(RPAD('', 1 + DATEDIFF(TIMESTAMP(end_date), TIMESTAMP(start_date)), '.'),'') AS h
      FROM YourTable), h
  )))
  HAVING DAYOFWEEK(business_day) NOT IN (1,7)
```

)

Comment: Thanks! But again, where would the table name go?

Comment: sorry, i thought it is obvious. added to answer